# How can I disable the JSHint Gutter package for one Sublime Text 3 project only

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I installed [JS Hint Gutter](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint) recently for use on most of the Javascript projects that I work on. It works great. However I recently started work on a React project that uses JSX, which of course causes warnings to be raised by JS Hint Gutter.

I followed a [guide](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#disabling-packages) from the Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation site on disabling packages so now I have a `.sublime-project` file in my project directory that looks like this:

```
{
    "settings":
    {
        "ignored_packages": 
        [
            "JSHint Gutter"
        ]
    }
}
```

The name that I used for JSHint Gutter was a guess based on the directory name it is stored in my Packages directory. I also tried `Sublime-JSHint`. Neither seemed to work because even after restarting Sublime I still get linting errors from JSHint Gutter.

How can I disable the JSHint Gutter package for this one single Sublime Text 3 project that I am working on? Is this question the same as how to get the exact name of a package to include in `ignored_packages`?

I also discovered that after installation the package directory contains a file `package-metadata.json`. It has keys like `description` but none like `name` that I could use to include in `ignored_packages`.